# MySQL Query to fuzzy(?) search a software database

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I have a software names database which i need to search ,now i am trying to find a query which will select the right software by name . The software name field is a `VARCHAR`

**Example software list in DB:**

```
Adobe Flash Professional
Mozilla Firefox Browser 20.0
Adobe Photoshop Lightroom
NetBeans IDE
WinRAR 5.10 beta 2
```

Query for firefox could be:
`Firefox` or `Mozilla Firefox`

Query for Lightroom could be:
`Lightroom` or `Adobe Lightroom` or `Photoshop Lightroom`

Query for WinRar could be:
`WinRar` or `WinRar archiver`

I have tried to work something with `SOUNDEX` or Levenshtein distance , but those do not return desired result .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for fulltext searching: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Note that you will need to create a `FULLTEXT` index on the searched column, and you may want to consider adding relevant keywords to it (so your abovementioned "archiver" also matches on something)

Answer (score 0):

If you can manipulate the query, use the [like operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like)

Eg: `SELECT * FROM SOFTWARE WHERE NAME LIKE '%Adobe%Lightroom%`

Comment: I dont think it will work it all cases , like with the _WinRar_ example .